# Expose Environment in Parceljs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, parceljs

I'm trying to expose a variable when building with [Parcel.js](https://parceljs.org), similar to the [Webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) but I haven't found out how to do it.

In development I want my API host to be different from my production one, so:

```
//development:
API_URL="http://localhost:8900/"

//production:
API_URL="/"
```

Currently Parcel supports the `module.hot` switch, which I could abuse for that since the hot module reloading is only enabled in development, but it would be nice to have a better way for this.

I also can check if `window.location.hostname` is `localhost`, but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For anyone still seeking an answer to this:

You can use Parcel.js's .env file support (by way of the dotenv package), [added in 1.5.0 (2018-01-23)](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/commit/50de97fb1239b7079f36c3897fe0c0c5f2e39070).

No additional config needed. Just make your .env files separated by the appropriate `NODE_ENV` (production, development, etc) and you can access variables via `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`. In your case, you could do:

*.env.development*

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8900/
```

*.env.production*

```
API_URL=/
```

And then use it by calling `process.env.API_URL` (no further imports needed) in your code as needed.

Comment: works perfectly, almost too easy. In my case I set the env variable on the `npm` script that builds my code, something like: `"build": "NODE_ENV=production parcel build`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. Where should `.env.development` and `.env.production` be in?

Comment: https://parceljs.org/env.html it says .env files should be along with the package.json file under the same dir. ;)

Comment: Are they included in the bundle? How do I access / set them in JS console?

Comment: It is included in the browser bundle. In js you can refer to it using process.env.BLAH like magic.